# How to design event listner for 1-to-many tasks?

Tags: java, spring

I am facing an design problem:

I have a parent task and multiple children tasks.

Each tasks is represented using an entry in database table:

parent:
`parent_table: id | status`

child:
`children_table: id | status | parent_id`

A parent tasks may contain several children tasks. Each task is long running.

I want to have parent status updated from `in_progress` o `complete` only when ALL children tasks completes.

One way to do this is using PULL model: I make a process constantly checking for a parent's children tasks completed or not.

Is it possible to use PUSH model? Specifically, I am planning to use Spring event listener.

Comment: I can't help you with the technical details but the push listener would have to know when all children are done. This could either be by checking against some number of children, a set of children (in case some could fire multiple events) or by the children to know who is last.

Comment: I think you mean to put the push listener on the parent side. And the parent need to keep information about children (e.g. # of children). This could be extra information on the parent table because currently the 1-to-many relationship is maintained by child->parent relationship. So maybe pull model is better than push in this senario?

Comment: That's hard to say without knowing more details. However, you could also go for some push-pull, i.e. whenever a child finishes have the parent (or whoever would pull) check whether all children are done now.